# Id of Jetpack composable for autotesting

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-resources

In my company's Android project we have several screens implemented using Jetpack Compose.
For autotesting purposes I have to provide some kind of resource-id for each composable element used on specific screen. In android xml we have @id field for that. How to implement the same id reference to the composable(s) on the specific screen for autotesting?
Many thanks for your upcoming answers! The following is the example of the target screen:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
internal fun ThankYouPageUi(
    activity: FragmentActivity?,
    viewModel: ThankYouPageViewModel,
    initParams: ThankYouPageInitParams,
    backgroundColor: Int,
) {
    when (val state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value) {
        is ThankYouPageState.Content -> {
            val thankYouPageStepInfo = state.data
            val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.lottie_confetti))

            Scaffold(
                backgroundColor = colorResource(id = backgroundColor),
                topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(activity, viewModel, initParams, backgroundColor)
                },
                bottomBar = {
                    BottomBar(viewModel, thankYouPageStepInfo)
                },
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp).testTag("column"),
                ) {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.45f)
                            .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
                        painter = painterResource(id = thankYouPageStepInfo.imageDrawableRes),
                        contentDescription = "",
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = thankYouPageStepInfo.title,
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.primary_label),
                        style = h2TextStyle,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .h2BaseLinePadding()
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 24.dp),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                    thankYouPageStepInfo.subtitle?.let { subtitle ->
                        Text(
                            text = subtitle,
                            color = colorResource(id = R.color.primary_label),
                            style = subtitle1TextStyle,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .subtitle1BaseLinePadding()
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(top = 12.dp),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }
                    Text(
                        text = thankYouPageStepInfo.body,
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.secondary_label),
                        style = body1TextStyle,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .body1BaseLinePadding()
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 12.dp),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                    if (thankYouPageStepInfo.showConfetti) {
                        LottieAnimation(
                            composition,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize(),
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else -> Unit
    }
}
```

I tried to use something like Modifier().///.///.testTag("myTag") in my composables - but that's not a desired solution

Comment: why using `testTag` is not a solution for your specific use case? I think there is no other way, and probably, for backwards compatibility for Android 7 or below you should also need to use `testTagsAsResourceId` as well (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsPropertyReceiver).testTagsAsResourceId())

Comment: @cesonha many thanks for your answer. testTag is indeed the most recommended solution for this problem, but there are several complications to appear while autotesting such tagged views. However I found none other solution, so it seems that it's the only way. Thanks again!